# Tracking Specific error causing record while doing batch update

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Is there any way to track the record which causes exception while performing batch update in hibernate, as i have set the jdbc_batch_size in the hibernate configuration file. the error is thrown only at the time of inserting the batch of records. is there any way to figure out the exact record number.                                                                                     Thanks, Saif

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.

Maybe you should try temporarily converting the batch update into a loop of individual updates so you can get a log of which update causes the issue?

You could also try setting hibernate to show the sql for the batch update with something like [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/) on how to implement it.